# How to draw circles of a given distance around nodes?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Around each station of bus routes as returned by a query to OverpassTurbo, I'd like to draw circles of a given radius eg. 1 mile.

MapCSS supports "[symbol-size](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/MapCSS)", but I couldn't find what unit it uses, and if there's a way to turn it into miles.

Thank you.

Comment: "symbol-size" could be pixels. Did you check it?

Comment: You can't do this with overpass turbo, size is in pixel and it depends on the zoom level. There's no way to specify something like 1 mile.

Comment: @mmd The `symbol-size` setting sounds as though it would affect the radius of the circles, but as you write, they are always of the same size on the screen. Is there a possibility to choose between something like small, large and standard?

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap is essentially a collaboratively edited database for geographical data.

Overpass is a read-only API-based data mining tool that allows you to query OpenStreetMap.

Neither of both is directly suitable for drawing.

### ipyleaflet

[ipyleaflet](https://pypi.org/project/ipyleaflet/) is a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) plugin which allows you to use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) to create interactive maps. There you can also draw circles:

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, Circle

center = (48.8708038, 11.0972531)

m = Map(center=center, zoom=8.1)
m.layout.width = "100%"
m.layout.height = "800px"

circle = Circle()
circle.location = (48.8708038, 11.0972531)
circle.radius = 2_000
circle.color = "green"
circle.fill_color = "green"
m.add_layer(circle)

display(m)  # Jupyter command; needs no import
```

You can also save it to a PNG / JPG: [Python ipyleaflet export map as PNG or JPG or SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44800396/562769)